# Automated Security Test in GitLab

Tags: automation, automated-tests, gitlab, gitlab-ci, zap

i'm trying to implement automation inside my GitLab project.

In order to perform security scan, i would like to use ZAP to go through all the URLs present in the 
project and scan them. It's clearly not possible to pass manually all the URLs, so i'm trying to find a way to make all the test as automated as possible.

**The problem is: how to reach all the URLs present in the application?**

I thought a way could be to pass them as a "variable" in the YML file, and use them as parameter in the ZAP command, something like that (see below).

Is this a reasonable solution? Is there any other way to perform an automated scan inside a repository (without passing manually the URLs)? 
Thanks

```
variables:
  OWASP_CONTAINER: $APP_NAME-$BUILD_ID-OWASP
  OWASP_IMAGE: "owasp/zap2docker-stable"
  OWASP_REPORT_DIR: "owasp-data"
  ZAP_API_PORT: "8090"
  PENTEST_IP: 'application:8080'

run penetration tests:
 stage: pen-tests
 image: docker:stable

    - docker exec $OWASP_CONTAINER zap-cli -v -p $ZAP_API_PORT active-scan http://$PENTEST_IP/html
```

Comment: When your write "... all the URLs present in the application", do you mean all possible URLs that your program will accept and handle? I don't know how your program works, but in the server programs I've used, it is possible to use pattern matching for URLs. This makes is a bit complicated to search through the repository for all URLs! Do you have some way of telling your program to output all of the URLs that it will handle?

Comment: The biggest problem is how to handle POST requests. If, for example, "normal" URLs (eg GET requests) are managed by ZAP and other tools, how can you "pass" post type requests (in automation environment)?

Comment: There are lots of options: spider/ajax spider the app,  proxy functional tests, import har, import OpenAPI definitions.

Comment: I belive, a spider/ajax won't help. How they are supposed to scan url like "https://example.com/v2/users/USER_ID/ ... " automatically? Another point is also Authentication. How can my automated sec test authenticate to my website? It seems much more challenging than what I thought...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn on a new feature flag (FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD) to enable a network per build. Then also services can reach each others (Available since GitLab runner 12.9). For more information see: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#networking

Working example owasp zap job in GitLab CI:

```
owasp-zap:
  variables:
    FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: 1
  image: maven
  services:
    - selenium/standalone-chrome
    - name: owasp/zap2docker-weekly
      entrypoint: ['zap.sh', '-daemon', '-host', '0.0.0.0', '-port', '8080',
          '-config', 'api.addrs.addr.name=.*', '-config', 'api.addrs.addr.regex=true', '-config', 'api.key=1234567890']
  script:
    - sleep 5
    - mvn clean test -Dbrowser=chrome -Dgrid_url=http://selenium-standalone-chrome:4444/wd/hub -Dproxy=http://owasp-zap2docker-weekly:8080
    - curl http://owasp-zap2docker-weekly:8080/OTHER/core/other/htmlreport/?apikey=1234567890 -o report.html
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - report.html
```

Comment: Hi Jon, really interesting! Actually after 1y i managed to come to a solution also alone, but i've to say it's really similar to zours :) I also used ZAP as service and curled the api to get the results. I also used the alias for the container to avoid problems with the ip address :) So really nice ;)